# Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have tried everything I constantly get this error, all my packages are up to date, I have verified this over and over again, thx

````
 >> 301|            <%

    302|         const roles = guild.cache.roles;

    303|         roles.forEach(r => {

    304|            %>```

Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at eval (/root/Hosted/Bot/dashboard/guild/manage.ejs:256:35)
    at manage (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:682:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/root/Hosted/Bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at renderTemplate (/root/Hosted/Bot/modules/dashboard.js:38:9)
    at /root/Hosted/BetaBot/modules/dashboard.js:214:5
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
````

Comment: Your particular error means that `guild.cache` is `undefined`.  You need to see why that is.

Comment: What do you have in `guild.cache`? Perhaps you should check if guild has this property using `guild.hasOwnProperty('cache')` and if it is there check if it's true...
`if(guild.hasOwnProperty('cache') && guild.cache) { ... }`
There might be a better solution to this but I don't know the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `guild` is a guild, *and not a collection of guilds*, then you want `guild.roles.cache`, not `guild.cache.roles`, just a small confusion some people get, v12 is a little harder for people to understand.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I'm sorry I am still new to discord.js v12. Thank you so much! Things are now working!

Comment: It's fine @TrissieTheHusky, if you want to lean a bit more about what's changed in v12, you can! There's a list of changes for v12 [right here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)!

Comment: I have another question. I keep getting an error that ```TypeError: message.guild.channels.get is not a function``` aswell as ```TypeError: guild.channels.filter is not a function```

Comment: `message.guild.channels.cache.get` is probably what you're looking for, if you are searching by ID though, you can do `message.guild.channels.fetch(id)` to make sure you get the data, just remember to get the promise result with `await` or somethin.

Comment: Everything is cached nice! It will help make everything harder whilist easier.

Comment: Heh. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​